# Tar or gzip the find result on AIX using single command

Tags: shell, unix, tar, aix

I am trying to write command which can look for the files which are older than 14 days and tar those files, I have tried many things but what happens is they **find result give the names of the file and the tar command just writes the name into one files**.

Command used:

```
find /dir/subdir/ -type f -mtime +14 | tar -cvf data.tar -T -
```

I am not strictly looking for gzip will also do.
Operating system is AIX

Comment: How many files do you expect?

Comment: 20 to 50 files, but they are small XML files so size should not be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider the following:

```
find /dir/subdir/ -type f -mtime +14 > file.list
tar -cvf data.tar -L file.list
```

You may need to modify the `find` call using something like `-print0` switch on Linux if your file names contain white space-like symbols.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use
find /dir/subdir/ -type f -mtime +14 -exec tar -cvf foo.tar {} \;